# Div 100% length deformat bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

in my design i need to have 3 bars across whole screen like showed on picture. I v managed that by this code
[image: Img with 100% div height]

```
div {height:94%;}
#yellowDiv {height:100%;}
#lightGreenDiv {height:100%;}
#darkGreenDiv{height:100%;}
body, html { height:100% }
```

And that worked great until i placed bootstrap modal. Because of div 94% it deformat bootstrap dialog like on image below:

Now when i remove div length 94%, bootstrap modal is not deformated and elements are not going outside of border but my main page design is broken.

Look of modal form after removed div height 94%

And this is how main page looks after removed div 94% height
[image: Main page broken]

My question is how to set div height to be across whole page like on first image but not to affect bootstrap dialog modal ?

Comment: You should provide your code in a fiddle or snippet!

Comment: I know that problem is in div height 94% but i don't know how to solve it and my app is big so i didn't upload code, just images.

Comment: Did you use any position in your divs? Cus if you do not set a position fixed or absolute, it dosen't take height 100%?

Comment: Could you please check the below link it will help you.
http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/OXpqJb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ideas.

1. Instead of applying the 94% height to `<div>` apply it to a class like `.divHeight: 94%` and then just add `class="divHeight"` to the `<div>` you want affected.  Right now you're applying 94% to any and all `<div>` on your site.
2. If these green bars are meant to be a background for your site, why not just use gradients?  The following code applied to say... your `body` or `html` element would accomplish the same effect while omitting the need for your 3 `<div>` elements entirely (subject of course to browser compatibility):

   ```
   .gradient-bg {
       background: rgba(196, 224, 97, 1);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 100%);
       background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1)));
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 100%);
       background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 100%);
       background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 100%);
       background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(196, 224, 97, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 33%, rgba(110, 178, 87, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 66%, rgba(0, 155, 67, 1) 100%);
       filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c4e061', endColorstr='#009b43', GradientType=1);
   }
   ```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/oLZVWX)

Comment: Those 3 bars are acting as 3 diffrent buttons so it cant be gradient. Can u please post code sample with solution 1 ?

Comment: I've created the following example on CodePen that uses 3 `div` elements within a `div` wrapper.  Each child `div` triggers a separate modal: http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/oLZVWX